# How to make image center horizontally in android

Tags: android

This is layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

even though I have mentioned `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, But still image is not centered.

How to make image horizontally centered? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: clean your project and see output .......

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of your screen?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one. You have to set match parent property for relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:text="abc"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your image `centerHorizontal` to your device screen then make `RelativeLayout` width `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` of your `<RelativeLayout>`.

It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's looking you have setup your `Relative Layout's` `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` so it will set it `left` aligned somewhere **because the property you have used in child `Image View` is `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` will not get effected so change your `Relative Layout` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`**.

**Use this code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You should appreciate answer with upvote if it is helpful to you. or also you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace RelativeLayout width

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content "
```

to

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Parent's width (RelativeLayout) should be `match_parent`

2) In ImageView use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` or `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

This will set your imageview horizontally center in device screen